# SQLiteで日付が連続になっているデータをまとめたい

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite3を使用し、以下のようなデータを想定しているのですが、「type_idが同一で、日付が連番となっているデータについて、(type_id、開始日、終了日）を抽出する」ことはできますでしょうか。

◇data
・id : Integer(primary key)
・type_id : Integer
・date : Date

実際のデータは、
| id | type_id | date             | 
|  1 |       1 | date(2017, 1, 1) | 
|  2 |       1 | date(2017, 1, 1) | 
|  3 |       1 | date(2017, 1, 2) | 
|  4 |       1 | date(2017, 1, 2) | 
|  5 |       1 | date(2017, 1, 3) | 
|  6 |       1 | date(2017, 1, 3) | 
|  7 |       1 | date(2017, 1,17) | 
|  8 |       1 | date(2017, 1,18) | 
|  9 |       1 | date(2017, 1,19) | 
| 10 |       1 | date(2017, 2, 1) | 
...
|  ? |       2 | date(2017, 1, 1) | 
...
のようになっています。

上の例で、期待するレスポンスは、

(1, date(2017, 1, 1), date(2017, 1, 3))
(1, date(2017, 1,17), date(2017, 1,19))
...

といった具合です。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: type_idと日付が一致・重複しているものを抽出しているようにも見えますが違いますか？

Answer (score 2):

- 1日後のエントリがないエントリを探す(*1)
- (*1)のエントリそれぞれについて、過去、かつ最近のエントリを探し、その日数差を求める
- (*1)と元のテーブルを結合し、過去、かつ上記日数差以内のエントリごとにまとめる

とすれば求まりますが、多数回の自己結合操作をしなければならない高コストなクエリを発行する必要があります

共通テーブル式の再帰を用いれば、より簡潔な記述ができると思います
https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html

```
SELECT
  MIN(T2.id) AS id,
  MIN(T2.date) AS date_min,
  MAX(T2.date) AS date_max
FROM (
  SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.type_id,
    T1.date,
    COALESCE(T1.date - MAX(T2.date), 365) AS diff
  FROM (
    /* ---- 同じ ---- */
    SELECT
      MIN(T1.id) AS id,
      MIN(T1.type_id) AS type_id,
      MIN(T1.date) AS date
    FROM
      my_table T1
    LEFT JOIN
      my_table T2 ON (T1.type_id = T2.type_id AND T1.date + 1 = T2.date)
    GROUP BY
      T1.type_id, T1.date
    HAVING
      MIN(T2.date) IS NULL
    /* ---- 同じ ---- */
  ) T1
  LEFT JOIN (
    /* ---- 同じ ---- */
    SELECT
      MIN(T1.id) AS id,
      MIN(T1.type_id) AS type_id,
      MIN(T1.date) AS date
    FROM
      my_table T1
    LEFT JOIN
      my_table T2 ON (T1.type_id = T2.type_id AND T1.date + 1 = T2.date)
    GROUP BY
      T1.type_id, T1.date
    HAVING
      MIN(T2.date) IS NULL
    /* ---- 同じ ---- */
  ) T2 ON (T1.type_id = T2.type_id AND T1.date > T2.date)
  GROUP BY
    T1.id,
    T1.type_id,
    T1.date
) T1
LEFT JOIN
  my_table T2 ON (T1.type_id = T2.type_id AND T1.date >= T2.date AND T1.date - diff < T2.date)
GROUP BY
  T1.id
ORDER BY
  T1.id
;
```